# Why are adjacent strings automatically concatenated in Python? Doesn't this no conform to PEP 20?

Tags: python

In python

> Two or more string literals (i.e. the ones enclosed between quotes)
>   next to each other are automatically concatenated.

For example:

```
>>> "Hello " "world"
"Hello World"
```

Per PEP 20:
 **Explicit is better than implicit.**

This does not seem very explicit to me, so why is this allowed?

Comment: Your example isn't quite correct - there's no space in your starting strings either after the "Hello" or before the "World", so the output should be "HelloWorld"

Comment: You should open up what you mean that is not explicit enough.

Comment: Python is not alone in this behaviour,C and awk for example.

Comment: That was a typo. Now fixed

Comment: Because that's how Guido made it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read [PEP 3126](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3126/):

> This PEP is rejected. There wasn't enough support in favor, the feature to be removed isn't all that harmful, and there are some use cases that would become harder.